# Git status still showing files as modified after discarding changes

Tags: git, git-checkout

Running `git checkout -- <filename>` discards the changes but it still shows up when I run `git status`. I have to run `git checkout -- <filename>` twice just so it disappears from `git status` as modified.

Comment: What operating system do you use? What is output of `git config -l` ?

Comment: This is most likely due to different *line ending* configurations on different PCs. Try changing it to `check in "as is", check out "as is"` either by reinstalling git or adjusting it via `.gitattributes` file for the current repository only.

Comment: @Basilevs I posted the output here https://imgur.com/MB1mbcK

Comment: @TimothyTruckle The repo does not have a .gitattributes file. How would I go about adjusting it there if I just create the file? I can't seem to find it on the docs here https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @MikooSaguindang yes, you simply crete it as a text file exactly like you would do with the `.gitignore` file which is also not there in a shiny new git repository.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle git config has core.autocrlf=false. Line endings are ignored.